# WriteObject not properly writing a Set?

Tags: java, java-7, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I hope I didn't just find a bug in Java! I am running JDK 7u11 (mostly because that is the sanctioned JVM allowed by my employer) and I am noticing a very odd issue.

Namely, I am chunking data into a `LinkedHashSet` and writing it to a file using the `ObjectOutputStream` daisy changed through the `GZIpOutputStream` (mentioning this just in case it matters).

Now, when I get to the other side of the program and `readObject()` I notice that the size always reads 68, which I is the first size. The underlying table can have many more or less than 68, but the `.size()` method always returns 68. More troubling, when I try to manually iterate the underlying `Set`, it also stops at 68.

```
while(...) {
    oos.writeInt(p_rid);
    oos.writeObject(wptSet);
    wptSet.clear();
    // wptSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // **This somehow causes the heapsize to increase dramatically, but it does solve the problem**
}
```

And when reading it

```
Set<Coordinate> coordinates = (Set<Coordinate>) ois.readObject();
```

the `coordinates.size()` always returns 68. Now, I could make a workaround by also `.writeInt()` the size, but I can only iterate through 68 members!

Notice the `wptSet = new LinkedHashSet<>()` line actually solves the issue. The main problem with that is it makes my heapsize skyrocket when looking at the program in JVisualVM.

Update:
I actually just found a viable workaround that fixes the memory leak of re-instantiating wptSet... `System.gc()` Calling that after each call to `.clear()` actually keeps the memory leak away.

Either way, I shouldn't have to do this and shipping out the `LinkedHashSet` should not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Does your `Coordinate` class implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: Yes it does `class Coordinate implements Serializable {`

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce. Otherwise we are basically guessing.

Comment: @Radiodef I agree, I should but I don't have the time right now to create a Minimal code base to run... given that I stumbled on running `System.gc()` which actually patches up the problem very well. I'm hoping someone who has experienced writing Set/Map objects that get cleared in a loop could possibly help here.

Comment: jdk11, man you are in the future! ;) I guess you mean jdk1.1, then you are really in the previous century...

Comment: What is the JDK v11? I don't think Java version numbers look like that...

Comment: JDK 7 (or JDK 1.7)  is certainly ok and used in many companies/businesses. I don't understand your _update_: when do you need to do a `map.clear()`, is it in a loop? can you provide a little bit more of information on the code context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I think I understand what you are asking.

Here is an example to reproduce...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<Object> theSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        final int size = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            theSet.add(i);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectsOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            objectsOut.writeObject(theSet);
            theSet.remove(i); // mutate theSet for each write
        }

        ObjectInputStream objectsIn = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOut.toByteArray()));

        for(;;) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((Set<?>)objectsIn.readObject()).size());
            } catch(EOFException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
3
3
3
```

What is going on here is that `ObjectOutputStream` detects that you are writing the same object every time. Each time `theSet` is written, a "shared reference" to the object is written so that the same object is deserialized each time. This is explained in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written.

In this case you should use [`writeUnshared(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared-java.lang.Object-) which will bypass this mechanism, instead of `writeObject(Object)`.

Comment: Bingo! I knew there had to be some Java trick going on here! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note, you should try to be more clear explaining your question(s), for example I've inferred that you were actually using `ObjectOutputStream` because `DataOutputStream` does not have a `writeObject` method. It was also not clear to me that you were doing *multiple* writes at all until I saw your comment that you were calling `clear` in a loop. Also Map/Set confusion. Perhaps the question was written too hastily.